# How do I apply basic authentication to a Google Maps API getTileUrl request in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, basic-authentication

When I call my external tileserver, it requires basic authentication, but there appears to be no way to add this.

We are using the latest production version of Google Maps API.

I call up the tile as follows:

```
                  chartMapLayer = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                        getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
                            var tileCoords = xyzToBounds(coord.x, coord.y, zoom).join(",");
                            return (ChartURL + '/?' +
                                'SERVICE=WMS' +
                                '&<params go here.....>' +
                                '&BBOX=' + tileCoords);
                        },
                        maxZoom: 17,
                        minZoom: 0,
                        name: "CHARTWORLD",
                        isPng: true,
                        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
                    });
```

If I use the same code to call a server set up with no basic authentication, it works fine.  When I call the server we need to, I receive 401 (Unauthorized) errors.

I have tried setting up an XMLHttpRequest override to append the header to all outgoing requests.  Worked for everything EXCEPT the map tile request....

I also tried setting up a proxy page...this approach did actually work, but the requests were being served synchronously, so each tile load was taking about quarter of a second.  And there were 16 of them, so it was a really poor user experience.

How do I add authentication to Google Maps API tile requests?

The WMS server I am using requires basic auth to be provided in the header and, as per the comments, does not accept query parameters.

I have created a proxy and this does work, but takes about 5-6 seconds to draw a full page of tiles on the map, compared to almost instantaneous when done without a proxy using a test server from the same provider without the authentication requirements.

I have tried this with an ashx and an aspx page.  My current code uses the aspx page.  It is called from the javascript within the getTileUrl function as below:

```
return ('Charts.aspx?p=' + ChartURL + '/?' +
                                'SERVICE=WMS' +
                                '¬VERSION=1.3.0' +
                                '¬REQUEST=GetMap' +
                                '¬FORMAT=image%2Fpng' +
                                '¬CSVALUE=10,5,20,10,1,2,1,500000,100000,200000,1' +
                                '¬CSBOOL=183' +
                                '¬TRANSPARENT=false' +
                                '¬LAYERS=ENC' +
                                '¬CRS=EPSG%3A3857' +
                                '¬STYLES=' +
                                '¬WIDTH=256' +
                                '¬HEIGHT=256' +
                                '¬OBJECTFILTERNEGATION=TRUE' +
                                '¬BBOX=' + tileCoords);
```

The code behind of the page this calls is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;


public partial class Pages_User_Charts : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Parameters = Request.QueryString["p"];
        string ChartAuth = "";

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["chartAuth"] != null)
            ChartAuth = HttpContext.Current.Session["chartAuth"].ToString();

        if (ChartAuth.Length > 0 && Parameters.Length > 0)
        {
            string url = String.Format(Parameters.Replace("¬", "&")); 
            System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
            wc.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
            wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + ChartAuth);
            byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(url);
            Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that no matter which method you chose, header, user:pass@, query param, the credentials will be exposed in the network request.

Comment: Proxy server solves both of these issues, assuming you have auth specific to your application that could be passed to the proxy server.

Comment: I see your point re the credentials being exposed, but the provider has told me they do not support query parameters anyway :(.  For the proxy, I tried this, as mentioned in the OP, and it worked, but the tiles were served very slowly and seemingly synchronously - note that this slowdown does not happen when using MapBox, or when using Google with a test server without authentication requirements.

Maybe my proxy page (tried .aspx and .ashx pages to act as a proxy) is not set up correctly?